# java logging level eclipse vs production

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6, maven-jetty-plugin

For some reason for my website, I am seeing different logging and format between my eclipse development ( debugging locally with jetty ) and the production machine ( tomcat ).  Why is that?

What I really want is to increase the logging level to FINE in eclipse, while I am debugging it, but then get rid of FINE in production.  But if I cannot do that, I would at least like the 2 places to behave similarly.

Some tomcat configuration.  Does not really explain what is happening with Eclipse/Jetty, but maybe it will give someone an idea on how to help me.

```
+ ls --color -lrt /etc/tomcat6/logging.properties /etc/tomcat6/log4j.properties
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   tomcat  547 Oct 30  2017 /etc/tomcat6/log4j.properties
-rwxrwx---. 1 tomcat tomcat 3753 Sep 14 20:37 /etc/tomcat6/logging.properties
+ grep level /etc/tomcat6/logging.properties
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = CONFIG
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = CONFIG
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = CONFIG
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/admin].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = ALL
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.level=FINE
+ more /etc/tomcat6/log4j.properties
log4j.rootLogger=debug, R 
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/tomcat.log 
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB 
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n 
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG, R
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]=DEBUG, R
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core=DEBUG, R
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.session=DEBUG, R
```

Edit 2: jetty is being use via the "jetty-maven-plugin" using the goal "jetty:run", if that helps any.

Edit 3: Changing log4j.properties did not remove "FINE" logging ( I changed all debug/DEBUG to INFO ).

Also, for tomcat, here it is running:

```
tomcat   24403     1  6 17:22 ?        00:00:27 /usr/java/latest/bin/java -Djavax.sql.DataSource.Factory=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory -classpath :/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat6/temp **-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties** **-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager** org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

I already showed part of the logging properties file above, but here is the full thing:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = CONFIG
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = CONFIG
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = admin.

5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = CONFIG
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
1catalina.java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$tF %1$tT %tZ] %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/admin].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/admin].handlers = 4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.level=FINE

5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
```

My biggest confusion is still my inability to see finer grained logging in my jetty/eclipse testing, where it would actually be helpful.

Comment: Are you using a logging utility like log4j? Also, if you're using Jetty and Tomcat, wouldn't you expect different logs?

Comment: Probably using normal logging, except where some library is using log4j or something else.  But my biggest point is that one place display "FINE" level logging ( tomcat/production ), the other does not ( eclipse/jetty ).  If I knew what was setting it to "INFO" in eclipse, maybe I could find what is setting it to "FINE" in production.

Comment: BTW, I was able to disable some of the FINE logging in /etc/tomcat6/logging.properties.  I am going to add that to my original question for clarity.

Comment: Are you talking about code of your own, or code from some library?  You could set log4j.debug=true and it will print out logs describing its own initialization, so you can see which files it reads and what they set things to.  Is the log config you want from code using log4j, or commons logging, or something else?  it would help narrow down which config file to look for...

Comment: I am debugging my own code in eclipse.  No idea how the logging currently enabled is enabled, or disabled, in eclipse.  I don't know where to look, thus my question.  I do know for a fact that in my tomcat environment, it shows MORE logging.  Based on the log4j.properties file I found, I might be able to turn off some of the finer logging, but that does not help with eclipse since I want to turn more fine tuned logging ON there.  Under eclipse/maven/jetty, I don't know how to control the logging level.

Comment: Oh, where would I set log4j.debug=true?  I mean that might help with my tomcat environment, but how do I do it in eclipse/maven/jetty?  Also, to answer you other question, I suspect some libraries I use use log4j, but my own code uses the normal java logging, not commons or log4j.  I guess maybe I need to confirm that, since it has been awhile since I looked at the logger I am using.